# Which DbSet to add when TPT using inheritance

Tags: .net, inheritance, entity-framework-6, table-per-type

Let's say that I have the following entities:

```
public class Person { ... }
public class Student : Person { ... }
public class Teacher : Person { ... }
```

In the context class, which of the following is better (and why ?)

- Create only `DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }` and retrieve students using `context.Persons.OfType<Student>()`, or
- Create 3 `DbSet`s (`DbSet<Person>`, `DbSet<Student>` and `DbSet<Teacher>`), or
- Create 2 `DbSet`s, only for the child types (`DbSet<Student>` and `DbSet<Teacher>`)

Thanks !

Comment: Do Student and Teacher have any properties defined in it?

Comment: Of course, I omitted this for brievety, but all classes are full-flavoured classes.

Comment: Matter of taste, or opinion.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks, could you elaborate a bit ?  Has it always been this way in older versions ?  I tought you wer forced to use the 1st option in older versions

Answer (score 0):

Create only `DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }` and decorate inheriting classes as follows

```
[Table("Students")]
public class Student : Person { ... }
[Table("Teachers")]
public class Teacher : Person { ... }
```

Reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I look for.  I'm able to make the mapping (I use fluent API instead of DataAnnotations), and everything works correctly, I'm able to use my entities.  My qurestion is more about the best practices when exposing DBSets in the context.

Comment: That's what my answer is suggesting: first approach is the write one. Only one DbSet.